# Single view still image reconstruction from camera tracks

Tags: modeling, camera, image, tracking

I'm working on a precise 3D reconstruction of a scene from a sparse set of pictures, meaning that my attempts at photogrammetry using available documents has failed so far due to the limited amount of camera poses. The workflow I have been using as of now consists in locating camera poses in space from known information (done) and then performing manual reconstruction from the pictures.

To achieve this second step, I figured that working with motion trackers located on the image in the Movie Clip Editor and projected into 3D space using Link Empty to Track would allow me to get the best results, since I could then manually adjust depth from the camera poses. In order for the Link Empty to Track to work correctly, I have scaled the camera using the X and Y properties of the object with trackers positionned on every corner of the image in the Movie Clip Editor. I have thus been able to get tracks in the 3D viewport corresponding to the image frame, meaning the X and Y scale of the camera seem right, but they unfortunately appear strangely shifted upwards along the Y axis. Do you know what parameter could be causing this? I thought of the Y and X shift parameters on the camera object but I can't really change them, since the image plane would not be well positionned relative to the camera scene...

[image: Positionned tracks for camera scaling in Movie Clip Editor]

[image: Resulting tracks in the 3D Viewport, after the camera has been scaled. The yellow object in the viewport is real-world data used to verify camera parameters and position, which is why I can't really modify the shift values]

[image: Other view in 3D viewport showing the shift issue]